# Programming Arduino for Mindflex

Tags: arduino-due, communication

I am learning brain wave programming from [Tinkernut](http://www.tinkernut.com/portfolio/homemade-mind-controlled-tv-remote/) tutorial.

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>
#include <Brain.h>
IRsend irsend;
Brain brain(Serial);
const int ledPin = 3; 
long interval = 500; 
long previousMillis = 0;
int ledState = LOW; 
int medValue;

void setup() {
  // Set up the LED pin.
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // Start the hardware serial.
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Expect packets about once per second.
  if (brain.update()) {
    Serial.println(brain.readCSV());
    // Attention runs from 0 to 100.
    medValue = brain.readMeditation();
  } 

  // Make sure we have a signal.
  if(brain.readSignalQuality() == 0) {
    // Send a signal to the LED.
    if (medValue < 50) {
    irsend.sendNEC(0x10EFA05F, 32); 
    delay(40);
    }
  } 
}
```

The above code by tinkernut controls a single button of a tv remote only if the meditation value drops below 50.

My question is,

**How to program arduino to control all the buttons of a tv remote ?**

Comment: Get more probes. Or move up to a real neural control tool.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can you please mention a real neural control tool ?

Comment: If I used more probes for different buttons then fluctuating meditation values could go out of control and tv goes crazy. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Instead of having more input sensors you could do some pattern matching? (Think morse code, but tbh I don't know much about these "mind control" sensor thingies, seems kind of limited to me)